# Detecting scrolling FPS for UIKit in Swift

Tags: swift, off-screen, color-blending

im working on color blending, offscreen-rendering topics. I can't find Core Animation option in Instruments in Xcode 13 to visualize it. How can I detect fps while table view or collection view is scrolling?